# Как выбрать одно обязательное поле из двух Flask-Form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

В flask-form можно задать свойство `required`. Но что если мне нужно обязательных не два поля, а хотя бы одно из них(телефон и email, например)?

Comment: Если бы было на чистом html+js, то перед отправкой формы проверял если оба поля пустые, то ругаться что хотя бы одно должно быть заполнено

Comment: @gil9red ну, если подразумевать учебный проект, то сойдёт, а так ведь это небезопасно

Comment: Ну да, на сервере тоже нужно проверять, а то мимо браузера прилетит запрос и здравствуй 5xx ошибка :)

Comment: @gil9red Просто я думал можно прямо в WTForms указать выбор из двух, видимо, нельзя(

Comment: я не говорил что в WTForms нельзя, а поддержал ваш комментарий про небезопасность

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут придётся добавить собственный валидатор.
Документация на тему: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/validators.html#custom-validators

К примеру:

```
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class RequiredIf(DataRequired):
    """Validator which makes a field required if another field is set and has a truthy value.
    Sources:
        - http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/validators.html
        - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463209/how-to-make-a-field-conditionally-optional-in-wtforms
    """
    field_flags = ('requiredif',)

    def __init__(self, other_field_name, message=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_field_name = other_field_name
        self.message = message

    def __call__(self, form, field):
        other_field = form[self.other_field_name]
        if other_field is None:
            raise Exception('no field named "%s" in form' % self.other_field_name)
        if bool(other_field.data):
            super(RequiredIf, self).__call__(form, field)
```